# change the position of the <li> element using php

Tags: php, mysql, html, parsing

I have few lists in my webpage like this for example it is in a DIV

```
<div id="list">

<li id = 1> 1 </li>
<li id = 4> 4 </li>
<li id = 5> 5 </li>
<li id = 2> 2 </li>
<li id = 3> 3 </li>
```

What i want to do is using html parser change the order to  like this

```
<div id="list">

<li id = 1> 1 </li>
<li id = 2> 2 </li>
<li id = 3> 3 </li>
<li id = 4> 4 </li>
<li id = 5> 5 </li>
```

Is this even possible?

EDIT:

Can anyone give me an idea of what the code can be?

Comment: post the code that outputs that list. You could also use javascript for a quick fix. Also that `div` should probably be a `ol`

Comment: This list is hardcoded into the html page, and yes i have <ul>

Comment: if it's hardcoded, can't you just manually reorder it?

Comment: I can but i want to know how to do it using php

Comment: If it is hardcoded as html, you can't change it because php won't parse it as it'l be outside <?php tag. If it is coming from some resource, then we can talk about it.

Comment: why is this question got voted down? I believe it is a valid question. He has unsorted HTML and he want to sort it using PHP.

Comment: As a side note, id's that start with digits are invalid in HTML.

Comment: so how can i change the position using php, I do not know what code i can use or how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Use http://php.net/manual/ru/class.domdocument.php class to manipulate with XML\HTML

Comment: would I have to use the tagname and get all the list IDs to change the position of them?, or can i do it without the IDs?